# angular directive scope: setting a default value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating a datepicker directive, part of its markup is:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="day" ng-options="day.nr for day in allDays">
```

I'm trying to define `allDays` in the `scope` attribute like this:

```
ehrApp.directive('datePicker', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      allDays: [
      {'nr': 1},
      {'nr': 2},
      {'nr': 3},
      (...)
      {'nr': 31}
      ]
    },
```

But it doesn't work, it fails with "TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the value inside the `scope` attribute of the directive configuration, which is where you'd define the isolate scopes the directive uses.  Instead of doing it there, do it either in your `link` function or in your `controller` function:

```
return {
   link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.allDays = [{nr : 1}];
   }
}
```

or

```
return {
   controller : function ($scope, $element) {
       $scope.allDays = [{nr : 1}];
   }
}
```